# Restrict typescript interface to not have few properties from parent

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

I have two typescript interfaces as below:

```
interface A {
    elem1: string;
    elem2: string;
    elem3: string;
    elem4: string;
}

interface B extends A {
   elem5: string;
}
```

Now I want that when I define a variable of type `B`, it should not have `elem1` and `elem2` from interface A.
Is there a way in typescript to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Omit Keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is your friend. It is a utility type that constructs a type by omitting the provided keys.

Here is an example

[TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/4WypKm)

```ts
interface A {
    elem1: string;
    elem2: string;
    elem3: string;
    elem4: string;
}

interface B extends Omit<A, "elem1" | "elem2"> {
   elem5: string;
}

// Error
const b: B = {
    elem2: 'sdsd',
    elem3: 'wewe',
    elem4: 'wewe',
    elem5: 'wewe',
    
}

// OK
const b1: B = {
    elem3: 'wewe',
    elem4: 'wewe',
    elem5: 'wewe',
}
```